# JSON encoded exceptions in TYPO3 extbase controller with JsonView

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

For my extbase-based TYPO3 CMS extension I created an ApiController with JsonView as view object. Returning values works like a charm, the correct header `Content-type: application/json` is set.

To return other responses like missing authorization messages or validation errors, I currently use:

```php
$data = ["errors" => [
    "status" => 401,
    "message" => "Missing access token"
]];
$this->throwStatus($status, null, json_encode($data));
```

When I use `$this->throwStatus()` the header  `Content-type: text/html` is set. Even if I manually set `header("Content-type: application/json");` before using `$this->throwStatus()`.

How can I create responses with the correct content type header?

Comment: Have you tried to set header with `$this->response->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json', true);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you throw the status, try to set the headers in the response object:

```
$this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json', true);
$this->response->sendHeaders();
```

If you are accessing your data through a dedicated pageType, you can set the header for this pageType in TypoScript:

```
myPageType.config.additionalHeaders {
   10 {
      header = Content-Type: application/json
      replace = 1
   }
}
```

I will add this to my post about the topic:  https://usetypo3.com/json-view.html

Comment: The `replace = 1` is the important line.